# On full rank submatrices of a construction

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices

Take two matrices $T_1$ and $T_2$ in $\mathbb Z^{n\times n}$ with entries uniformly in $[-b,b]\cap\mathbb Z$ at some $b>0$. The matrices will be of rank $n$ each with probability at least $1-\frac1{\Omega(n^2)}$. Form a matrix $T_3$ of size $n^2\times n$ with rows of $T_3$ being difference of rows of $T_1$ and $T_2$. Since $T_1$ and $T_2$ are random we will have all rows of $T$ distinct with probability $1-o(1)$.

For every row $i\in\{1,\dots,n^2\}$ in $T_3$ form an $n\times n$ matrix $M_i=T_3[i]'\times T_3[i]$ where $'$ is transpose and $T_3[i]$ is $i$th row of $T_3$ and consider the matrix $N_i=(M_i+M_i')-Diag(M_i)$ where $Diag(M_i)$ is diagonal matrix consisting of diagonal entries of $M_i$. Form a matrix $T$ of size $n^2\times\Big(n+\frac{(n-1)n}2\Big)$ with $i$th row of $T$ being the diagonal and top right entries of $N_i$.

What is the probability that the rank of

> 1. $T$ is $\Big(n+\frac{(n-1)n}2\Big)$ for a given $b$?
> 2. a random $\Big(n+\frac{(n-1)n}2\Big)\times\Big(n+\frac{(n-1)n}2\Big)$ submatrix is $\Big(n+\frac{(n-1)n}2\Big)$ for a given $b$?

Comment: The probability that your matrix $T_1$ is singular is in $e^{-O(n^2)}$ (for a fixed $b$).

Comment: e^n^2 is technically Omega(n^2) and so I didn't bother since latter suffices for purpose of problem..

Comment: To clarify...  $M_i$ is symmetric (yes?).  And to say it with fewer matrices, you start with random vectors $u_i$ and $v_j$, then for each pair, you cook up matrices $N_{i,j}$ and say $S$ is the collection of these $n^2$ matrices.  You want to know the chance that $S$ spans the space of symmetric matrices.  And you also care about the chance that a random subset (of correct size) is a basis.  Right?

Comment: I figured you don't get any with this concoction.